# How to stop dhcp discover messages after dhcp release?

Tags: networking, dhcp

I configured a wrong interface as dhcp and did a `ifdown` and `ifup` on that interface. DHCP client keeps sending DHCP discover messages and I had to wait for a while for it stop. `ctl+z` or `ctl+c` didn't really work.

Is there a way to stop that instead of waiting for a long time.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the **PID** of the DHCP Client with `pgrep`. Read `man pgrep`. You can kill (send a signal to) by name with `pkill`. `man pkill`.

Comment: yeah but to do that, I have to stop the DHCP discover message stream first. (Unless I have another screen running in the background)

Comment: Open another `ssh` connection, or just type your command - output from a backgrounded process does not corrupt input.

Comment: Read `man ssh`. Use `~B` to send a Break to target.